# Is it legal to create StackOverflow Android app?

Tags: discussion

Are we allowed to create android app which points to stack overflow sites ?
Can we name it "StackOverFlow" ?
Will it cause any legal issues ?
How can we do that ?

Comment: I'll let someone more familiar with the TOS comment on the legality of naming it... but creating the app certainly won't be a problem.  Several apps already exist, and Stack Exchange is developing their own (in Beta testing now).

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/legal

Comment: @psubsee2003 - The android app is now in the app store, in open Beta.

Comment: @thank Oded, missed that bit of news... I have edited

Comment: [Legal and even encouraged](http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/android+app) assuming you're using the API properly and give proper attribution. :-)

Comment: @psubsee2003 - it happened over this weekend, so understandable ;)

Comment: Where can i get API for that ? Do they charge for that ?

Comment: To get you started: http://stackapps.com/

Comment: @vengets they don't charge anything, more views means more money to SE after all. :)

Comment: I'm fairly certain you [can't call it that name...](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance) _"Including one of the terms, "Stack" or "Exchange" or "Overflow" in your product name is generally okay."_ ... _"Do not use our name in the name of your product."_.